# What is meant by a 'definite value' in physics?

Tags: terminology, definition, physical-constants

1. What are the allowed values of a constant when a physical theory mentions that a constant is has a '*definite*' value (for example, definite velocity *c* in special relativity). What is meant with the addition of 'definite'? Is it to exclude infinity? What about zero?
2. Is a *universal* constant always assumed to have a non-zero and non-infinite value?

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: Edited by adding example of special relativity.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking about “[SI defining constants](https://www.nist.gov/si-redefinition/meet-constants)”?

Comment: I've never heard of a *definite* constant. Can you give some context? Maybe a link to where you saw the phrase used?

Comment: Yes. But I'm especially curious about the terminology. For example when Einstein talked about a his cosmological constant, could that constant take any value including 0 and infinity? Or is implicit he meant a non-zero, non-infinite value.

Comment: Edited to 'definite value' instead of 'definite constant'.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/definite Usually, in physics you have to forget most of the word's meanings you have learned in mathematics. Definitely ;-)

Comment: More on [definite in physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Adefinite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definite doesn’t mean anything special. It just emphasises it is a constant and that it’s value is important for the theory. A constant can be zero, but then it isn’t there so there is no point talking about it. A constant cannot be infinite. Infinity is not something you can measure; it is a purely mathematical concept; albeit very useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Couldn't the speed of light be infinite?